# package com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.dynamic does not exist

Tags: java, ant, java-8, java-7

I am trying to compile a java file, which uses package `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.dynamic`, using ANT-1.9.3 but I'm receiving error

> package com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.dynamic does not
>   exist

I tried compiling both JDK7 and JDK 8 and getting the same error.

I can see the package exist inside `rt.jar` of both JDK. I have set `JAVA_HOME` also properly.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know what build system you are using, maybe you can provide more details. In any case, if it's Gradle check this link: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/problem-with-jar-that-contains-java-sources/2294
It might help.

Comment: Do not use `com.sun.*` packages. They are internal APIs that should not be used by your own programs directly. They can change or disappear in any new Java version.

Comment: The word “internal” even is contained in the package name…

Comment: As I mentioned in question the build system I am using is ANT(Maven or Gradle not supported by my organization). I understand that we should not use "com.sun.*" packages , but the project has been developed by other team and I am just trying to integrate ANT build into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, this behaviour is probably intentional and your usage is deliberately unsupported. If your code used to compile under Java6 and now doesn't under Java7 or Java8 then you've basically fallen foul of

> From one release to another, these classes may be removed, or they may be moved from one package to another

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

See also http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6778491 for a technical description of a possible cause of not being able to compile a class which references a 'com.sun.*' class but which throws the same compiler error you're seeing despite the fact that the referenced class exists in rt.jar. Also for the kind of response which Oracle give to bug reports relating to it;)

Unfortunately, using undocumented, unsupported APIs often has this kind of 'bite you in the posterior' kind of effect.

Answer (score 2):

Please add the line, < compilerarg line="-XDignore.symbol.file" compiler="modern"/ >  for < javac > tag in your build.xml. This should solve your problem. It solved for me.

For reference you can view the forum link
http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/19871.page#sthash.srrN9Ijk.dpbs